# Trying to perform sum of count using group by and union

Tags: sql, oracle, count, group-by, union

I am trying to sum the counts of three queries using union. These queries also contain group by clauses within them. Below is my query that I have written:

```
select 
       extract(year from start_date), 
       extract(month from start_date),
       APPLICATION_TYPE,
       sum(TOTAL) as Overall_TOTAL
from (
select 
       extract(year from A.start_date) as Start_Year, 
       extract(month from A.start_date) as Start_Month,
       A.APPLICATION_TYPE as Type,
       count(A.TRANSACTION_NUMBER) as Total
from lnr_application A
where 
      A.START_DATE >= to_date('&sdate','DD/MM/YYYY')
      and A.START_DATE <= to_date('&edate','DD/MM/YYYY')  
      and A.permission_type = 'HRW'
      and A.status_cd in ('AP')
group by extract(year from start_date), extract(month from start_date), A.APPLICATION_TYPE
union all
select 
       extract (year from A.tstamp) as Start_Year, 
       extract (month from A.tstamp) as Start_Month, 
       A.application_type as Type,
       count(A.transaction_number) as Total
from lnr_application A
where 
      A.permission_type = 'HRW'
      and A.status_cd in ('RF')
      and trunc(A.tstamp) >= to_date ('&sdate','dd/mm/yyyy')
      and trunc(A.tstamp) <= to_date ('&edate','dd/mm/yy')
group by extract (year from A.tstamp), extract (month from A.tstamp), A.application_type 
union all
select 
       extract (year from A.tstamp) as Start_Year, 
       extract (month from A.tstamp) as Start_Month, 
       A.application_type as Type, 
       count(A.transaction_number) as Total
from lnr_application A
where 
      A.permission_type = 'HRW'
      and A.status_cd in ('CL')
      and trunc(A.tstamp) >= to_date ('&sdate','dd/mm/yyyy')
      and trunc(A.tstamp) <= to_date ('&edate','dd/mm/yy')      
group by extract (year from A.tstamp), extract (month from A.tstamp), A.application_type
) tmp
group by extract(year from start_date), extract(month from start_date), APPLICATION_TYPE
order by extract(year from start_date), extract(month from start_date), APPLICATION_TYPE
```

When I execute the query, I get an error message that `Start_Date` is an invalid identifier. If I remove the sum component from the top i.e. just union all three queries, I get the below result:

```
2011    7   A   627 
2011    7   A   21 
2011    7   A   1 
2011    7   C   1585 
2011    7   C   1    
2011    7   I   1 
2011    7   I   154 
2011    7   I   3
```

I want to total the sum of the counts for the respective year, month and application type, as below:

```
2011    7   A   649
2011    7   C   1586 
2011    7   I   158
```

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

In the SELECT statement of the union, you need to use Start_Year and Start_Month instead of the EXTRACT statements. Also, use Type instead of Application_Type.

Comment: @bdamania, Great to hear.  As you are new, it would be a good idea to mark the answer as "Answered" so that others can see that it was the solution that worked for you.   You do this by clicking the checkmark next to the answer (under the upvote/downvote buttons).  You can do this regardless of reputation.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine the three union all subqueries into a single query, and then you don't need the extra inline view, leading to this simple query:

```
select extract(year from a.start_date)
     , extract(month from a.start_date)
     , a.application_type
     , sum(a.total) as overall_total
  from lnr_application a
 where a.permission_type = 'HRW'
   and a.status_cd in ('AP','RF','CL')
   and a.tstamp between to_date('&sdate','dd/mm/yyyy') and to_date('&edate','dd/mm/yyyy') + interval '1' day - interval '1' second
 group by extract(year from a.start_date)
     , extract(month from a.start_date)
     , a.application_type
 order by extract(year from a.start_date)
     , extract(month from a.start_date)
     , a.application_type
```

And simplifying some more, by using trunc(...,'mm') instead of two times extract:

```
select extract(year from trunc(a.start_date,'mm'))
     , extract(month from trunc(a.start_date,'mm'))
     , a.application_type
     , sum(a.total) as overall_total
  from lnr_application a
 where a.permission_type = 'HRW'
   and a.status_cd in ('AP','RF','CL')
   and a.tstamp between to_date('&sdate','dd/mm/yyyy') and to_date('&sdate','dd/mm/yyyy') + interval '1' day - interval '1' second
 group by trunc(a.start_date,'mm')
     , a.application_type
 order by trunc(a.start_date,'mm')
     , a.application_type
```

Regards,
Rob.

Comment: Hi Rob, many thanks for your response. I am guessing that simplification will not work for me, as the first sub-query has a constraint on Start_DATE where the status is AP, and the other two where the STATUS is CL and RF, the constraint is on TSTAMP. Hence, guessing it needs to be separate. However, changing the extract statement to the alias, wrked for me.

Comment: Ah, I missed that. You could still do a `( (status_cd = 'AP' and a.start_date between ...) or (status_cd in ('RF','CL') and (a.tstamp between ...) )`, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
       Start_Year, 
       Start_Month,
       APPLICATION_TYPE,
       sum(TOTAL) as Overall_TOTAL
from (
select 
       extract(year from A.start_date) as Start_Year, 
       extract(month from A.start_date) as Start_Month,
       A.APPLICATION_TYPE as Type,
       count(A.TRANSACTION_NUMBER) as Total
from lnr_application A
where 
      A.START_DATE >= to_date('&sdate','DD/MM/YYYY')
      and A.START_DATE <= to_date('&edate','DD/MM/YYYY')  
      and A.permission_type = 'HRW'
      and A.status_cd in ('AP')
group by extract(year from start_date), extract(month from start_date), A.APPLICATION_TYPE
union all
select 
       extract (year from A.tstamp) as Start_Year, 
       extract (month from A.tstamp) as Start_Month, 
       A.application_type as Type,
       count(A.transaction_number) as Total
from lnr_application A
where 
      A.permission_type = 'HRW'
      and A.status_cd in ('RF')
      and trunc(A.tstamp) >= to_date ('&sdate','dd/mm/yyyy')
      and trunc(A.tstamp) <= to_date ('&edate','dd/mm/yy')
group by extract (year from A.tstamp), extract (month from A.tstamp), A.application_type 
union all
select 
       extract (year from A.tstamp) as Start_Year, 
       extract (month from A.tstamp) as Start_Month, 
       A.application_type as Type, 
       count(A.transaction_number) as Total
from lnr_application A
where 
      A.permission_type = 'HRW'
      and A.status_cd in ('CL')
      and trunc(A.tstamp) >= to_date ('&sdate','dd/mm/yyyy')
      and trunc(A.tstamp) <= to_date ('&edate','dd/mm/yy')      
group by extract (year from A.tstamp), extract (month from A.tstamp), A.application_type
) tmp
group by Start_Year, 
       Start_Month,
       APPLICATION_TYPE
order by Start_Year, 
       Start_Month,
       APPLICATION_TYPE
```

Comment: Thanks Florin, Holger pointed out the same thing, much appreciated.